# Is it possible to install a MS SQL Express Studio, where the studio tool also is included?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am facing the following problem:

I want to have a Express (=free) version of MS SQL Server and there I want to be able to see the SQL Management Studio interface. I have found only installations where there is the SQL Server Configuration Manager which has more limited list of features and of course I want to use a feature that does not exist in it.

So as the title says:

> Is it possible to install a MS SQL Express Studio, where the studio tool also is included?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is also the MS SQL Express 2008 R2 *WITH ADVANCED SERVICES* that is interesting:

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=1842

Includes not only SSMS but also Reporting Services...

(the older 2005 version is also still around, here: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5897

Hope that helps!

Comment: I had to find 10.50.1617 version or one near to it. Closest is [10.50.1600.1](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=25174) so far. It is not so easy to find specific version for download. Is there any tricks on that?

Comment: Two resources: [https://sqlblog.org/2011/06/14/security-updates-for-all-supported-versions-of-sql-server ] and [http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=26727 ]. I don't bother looking up, but 10.50.1617 sounds like a few (security) updates have been applied to the installation (SP1 is v 10.50.2500).

Comment: thanks for the comment. Version 10.50.1600.1 gave me what I wanted.

Answer (score 4):

You are probably better off with the newer version of Management Studio Express (which will work against 2008 R2, 2008 and 2005):

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=22985

The reason is that if you use the 2008 version and try to manage a 2008 R2 instance, for example, you may run into issues. Always better to have the client tools >= the highest version of the engine that you need to support.

Note that Management Studio Express is missing some of the SSMS functionality, such as managing agent, so if you have to manage other editions you may be better off investing $49 (or less, depending on vendor) into developer edition, which comes with the full version of SSMS:

http://bit.ly/oPq7NY

Answer (score 0):

I found the working version on http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=7593#instructions